# Is scanner and Lexical analyzer same?

Tags: compilers, lexical-analysis

Today I read that

> The scanner is a subroutine which is frequently called by an
>   application program like a compiler. The primary function of a scanner
>   is to combine characters from the input stream into recognizable units
>   called tokens.

But isn't it the job of lexical analyzer? Are they both the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. These are two different words for the same thing. I've also heard it called a lexer sometimes.